# Possible bug in the SO Markdown

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, markdown-rendering

I was browsing through question today and clicked on a question : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019409/how-to-get-a-mail-id-in-the-selected-username-by-using-jquery-in-grails)

It had a title which made sense but the question content :
[image]

I thought the `Enter code here` was a formatting issue so went on to edit it and found :

[image]

Then I realized that the whole code put up there wasn't showing up because the OP had clicked on `{}`[code sample] and then pasted their code. But why is the code hidden?

I think this is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: The question you linked has been fixed.

Comment: @JeffArries yes I have edited it, but why is the text getting hidden was my question.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  But I just wanted to let you know that people could't reproduce the issue. Just trying to help!

Comment: @JeffArries I know that, that's the reason I had put the images. Anyway, Its answered below.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to format multiple lines of code in markdown is to indent each line 4 spaces in.

The OP has used a single ` mark at the start and end of the whole listing, which is not correct - these are for inline code.

As result, only the first line of their markup shows up as code, but the rest is not visible as it is rendered with tags.

This is not a bug - it is someone who doesn't understand how to use markdown.

Comment: Its true that the user didn't know how to use the markdown & used a single line tag for a multi-line code. But why is the code hidden? shouldn't it display the rest of the code even when its markdown is wrong?

Comment: Why was it hidden? Because it was rendered as is. When you type in `<b>bold</b>` do you expect to see the `<b>` and `</b>` in the browser? Or just a bolded **`bold`**? This is how browsers render tags. How would you expect the browser to render a `<div>`?

Comment: Additionally - since the parser doesn't see these as code, it will strip out any unknown/dangerous elements from the content before rendering it, so much of the post will be stripped out in this case.

Comment: ok. I thought raw tags would be visible..  Like this : <div> </div>

Comment: Of course not. They need to be escaped to be seen as tags on the page - you don't see `<div>` tags all over sites, do you?

Comment: No.. What I mean was like it came up in the comment, it should have come up in the answer too..

Comment: We escaped it in the comments, as we do not allow tags in comments. In answers (or questions) we have to allow for them (as valid markdown) - comments allow for a very limited subset of markdown.

Comment: oh, so its only in comments that we can do that. thanx.